# include commas in strings when saving to_csv - pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':'ble','y':[[1,2]]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':'bla','y':[np.array([1,2])]})

df1.to_csv('df1.csv', sep='\t')
df2.to_csv('df2.csv', sep='\t')
```

`df1.csv` will preserve commas

```
x   y
ble [1, 2]
```

but `df2.csv` won't

```
x   y
bla [1 2]
```

the data frames are then concatenated (`df3.csv`)

```
x   y
ble [1,2]
bla [1 2]
```

I read `df3.csv` later in python and convert `y` back into lists with `ast._literal_eval`, but this won't work for the second line. Can I somehow tell `to_csv` to include commas regardless of whether it's a python list or numpy array?

Comment: i suggest use [`to_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) to store python objects for trusted data: `df1.to_pickle('df1.pkl')`
`df2.to_pickle('df2.pkl')` and read using `pd.read_pickle('df2.pkl')` , that way you will not have to do `ast.literal_eval` either as it will store a list as a list and array as array , but please go through the warnings too as mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: `to_csv` writes the `str` representation to the file.  For a list that has the '[1,2]', for a ndarray '[1 2]'.  When loaded, both will be strings. Thus `csv` is not a good format for saving this dataframe.

Comment: If you need a text file, then you can also use ```df.to_json(fn)`` and then read it back with ```pd.read_json(fn)``` CSV is not really designed for nested data structures.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply seeing the difference in the `str` representation of the two classes:

```
In [215]: print([1,2])                                                                         
[1, 2]
In [216]: print(np.array([1,2]))                                                               
[1 2]
```

In one of your test cases, the array is embedding in a list, with a different representation:

```
In [227]: pd.__version__                                                                       
Out[227]: '0.25.3'
In [228]: df=pd.DataFrame([{'x':'ble','y':[[1,2]]}, 
     ...: {'x':'bla','y':[np.array([1,2])]}, 
     ...: {'x':'bli','y':np.array([1,2])} 
     ...: ])                                                                                   
In [229]: df                                                                                   
Out[229]: 
     x         y
0  ble  [[1, 2]]
1  bla  [[1, 2]]
2  bli    [1, 2]
In [230]: df.to_csv('test.csv')                                                                
In [231]: cat test.csv                                                                         
,x,y
0,ble,"[[1, 2]]"
1,bla,"[array([1, 2])]"
2,bli,[1 2]
```

You should `to_csv`, but it appears that we don't have fine control over this.  Remember `csv` is meant to store simple tables, rows of columns.  So is the DataFrame.  Storing lists or arrays in an element is an extra level of nesting that does not fit that format well.